# SQLite: Writing Trigger That Catches Insertions

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
SIGHTINGS (NAME, PERSON, LOCATION, SIGHTED)
FEATURES (LOCATION, CLASS, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, MAP, ELEV)
FLOWERS (GENUS, SPECIES, COMNAME)
```

I want to write a trigger that catches inserts into the `SIGHTINGS` table, and lets the user know when there is a potential foreign key problem. I want the trigger to print an error if the the thing that was just inserted references something that does not currently exists in the table.

Something in the manner of: "Insert into the SIGHTINGS table references location 'Grous Meadow'
that is not found in the database"

I looked into

```
RAISE(ABORT, `Some random message`)
```

But I could get anywhere since I'm not sure how to implement this. How would I do this?

Comment: Why not just declare a `foreign key` constraint?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Because this homework question (which I'm seeing for the third time in as many days) wants something different.